# My website contains a couple of joblistings, so for that how will fetch those joblisting contents and make it displayed in the android app

Tags: android, wordpress, parsing

My website contains a couple of job-listings, so for that how will fetch those job-listing contents and make it displayed in the android app, i followed json parsing tutorials but still din get the output, please can anybody help in.

Comment: ...not without you posting [what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)...

Answer (score 0):

Try following these tutorial. Might help your cause.

1. http://www.ingeniumblog.net/2012/01/making-a-slick-rss-reader-in-android/
2. http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/simple-android-json-parsing-example-with-output-into-listactivity/